# TDBGrid keeps selection in the middle of the list?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I've been testing/using my application that has a `TDBGrid` and all movement/selection/etc.. working as expected for months.  All of a sudden in the middle of today (working fine an hour ago) when I select something with the mouse, it selects it but moves everything so the selected item is in the middle.  Same if I use the arrows, it keeps it in the middle until at the beginning / end of the grid then will move the selection.

I thought may a scroll-lock issue, I try hitting that, no difference.  I went in to excel, hit scroll-lock to see it enable/disable and ensured it wasn't on.   Still `TDBGrid` acting weird.  I tried exiting the app and starting it again, same issue. I figure I'll have to reboot the computer?

What is this action and how to you enable/disable it?

TIA!!